# IndexOutOfRangeException with array.Length>0 while reading array[1]

Tags: c#

I'm coding on an online IDE that doesn't expose either the program input nor the stdout output, in this particular case (input too big).

Considering `file` to be an arbitrary string:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
{
    string[] splitted = file.Split('.');
    if (splitted.Length > 0)
    {
        string Test = splitted[1];
    }
}
```

How is it possible that the code above returns this error:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: ~message masked~ 
  at Solution.Solution.Main (System.String[] args) [0x000e4] in solution.cs:6
```

Line number is always wherever I try to access `splitted[1]`. This doesn't make any sense: if `splitted.Length > 0` then `splitted[1]` exists.

Is this a bug of the online IDE? Or is there any condition in which a C# string[] can be of Lenght>0 and throw IndexOutOfRangeException while reading it's value at [1]?

Comment: If the `Length` is 1, then `splitted` will have a single element, accessible with the expression `splitted[0]`.  Therefore `splitted[1]` may use an index that is out of range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're checking if the array is longer than 0, then trying to reference the *second* element within the array.  If the length is 1, that's an error.

If you always need the second element, check that the array has at least two elements:

```
if (splitted.Length > 1)
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to access the *first* element:

```
string Test = splitted[0];
```

Comment: Oh my god... I'm so stupid. Somehow it didn't cross my mind that Length of a split will always be >0. Thanks.

Comment: @Saturnix "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."

Answer (score 0):

In c#, array indexing starts at `0`. It looks like in the line of code `string Test = splitted[1];` that you're trying to access the first element in `splitted`, but since indexing starts at `0`, the element in index `1` will be the second.

You want to change this to `string Test = splitted[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C# always begins indexing with 0. You should try splitted[0]

Answer (score 0):

C# uses zero based index. Splitted[0] is guaranteed to exist in your conditional as that is the first element in the array. Splitted [1] is the second element in the array.